# Apache Cassandra COPY TO command failing with errors={}, last_host=10.19.2.3226.81 rows/s

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cqlsh

I am attempting to copy the contents of one table to another (to recreate the partition key) using the `COPY TO` command via cqlsh.  However, it gets so far (typically circa 50,000 records) and then fails with the following error:

> [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.9.791 | DSE 4.8.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
>
> cqlsh> COPY keyspace_name.flat_timeseries TO 'test.csv';
>
> errors={}, last_host=10.19.2.3226.81 rows/s

This table contains approx 5M records - so not getting anywhere near to the end of the process.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in cassandra 2.1.14 and above
[CASSANDRA-11053](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11053)

You can use other utility like SSTableLoader

Comment: Thanks for the info - but I cannot see any mention within that bug fix of my explicit problem.